# How collapse/expand programmatically an AppBarLayout in Android?

Tags: java, android

My issue is that I wanted go top and bottom programmatically of a default project Scrolling Activity with an added NestedScrollView.

Like when you use your finger to go top (the top screen expand) or bottom (the top screen contract).

[image]

Answer (score 0):

After researching hours I found this simple solution:

```
    if (id == R.id.action_goto_top) {
        AppBarLayout abl = findViewById(R.id.app_bar);
        abl.setExpanded(true);
        NestedScrollView nsv = findViewById(R.id.content_scrolling);
        nsv.fullScroll(View.FOCUS_UP);

        return true;
    }

    if (id == R.id.action_goto_bottom) {
        AppBarLayout abl = findViewById(R.id.app_bar);
        abl.setExpanded(false);
        NestedScrollView nsv = findViewById(R.id.content_scrolling);
        nsv.fullScroll(View.FOCUS_DOWN);

        return true;
    }
```